# How to calculate the probability that the distance between two points is less than some value?

Tags: probability

If I have two points $A=(x_A, y_A)$ and $B=(x_B, y_B)$ generated uniformly ate random in 2D Euclidean space. Here, I assume $0­\le x_A, x_B, y_A, y_B \le 100$. I would like to calculate the probability that the distance between them, $d_{AB}$, is smaller than some given constant $\alpha$.

This is given by

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[d_{AB}\le \alpha] = &\;\mathbb{P}\left[\sqrt{(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2}\le \alpha\right]\\=&\;\mathbb{P}\left[(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2\le \alpha^2\right]
\end{align}
$$

How can I finish this?

Comment: Your hypothesis contain a contradiction: you say for first that $A$ and $B$ come from a uniform probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it does not exist), then that $A$ and $B$ belong to a square. So, which of the two? Maybe $A$ and $B$ come from a uniform distribution over a square?

Comment: Anyway, if $A$ and $B$ are two random point of the unit square, the exact probability $\mathbb{P}[|A-B|\leq \alpha]$ is given by a tough integral, but if $\alpha$ is small, $\pi\alpha^2$ is a good approximation for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes it is an uniform distribution over a square. Do you have any reference that calculate the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you require the probability that $B$ lies within a disk or radius $\alpha$ from $A$.

Whenever $A$ lies more than $\alpha$ from the edge this is $ 10^{-4}\pi\alpha^2$.   For sufficiently small $\alpha$ this is a reasonable approximation of the required probability.

It will be somewhat less if there is a significant probability that $A$ lying within $[0;\alpha)$ from an edge *or* two (*or* maybe three or four for really large $\alpha$).   The calculation of which would involve the equation for the areas of circle cut by chords.   When $\alpha<100$ this would look something like

$$10^{-4}\big(\pi\alpha^2 - 400\int_0^{\alpha} \operatorname {chordSlice}(x,\alpha)\operatorname d x +4\int_0^{\alpha}\!\!\!\int_0^{\alpha}\operatorname {twoChordSlice}(x,y,\alpha)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y \Big) $$