# Expected number of points inside a disc with center inside a square

Tags: probability, geometry

Let's say we have $n$ points that are uniformly, identically, and independently distributed in a square of side length $l$. Now, we take a disk of radius $r\leq l/2$ with the center randomly placed inside the square. How many points are expected to be inside the disk?

Initially, I was making an approximation based on the areas of the disk and square:
$$\frac{\pi r^2 n}{l^2}.$$

However, this ignores the fact that when the center of the disk is closer to the edge, we would have a lesser number of points.

So, I tried dividing the main square into parts, as shown in the figure below. AKME is a square of side of side $r$. Now, the previous result holds true for the innermost square region, with reduced side length. I will need to find out the expected area for one of the smaller squares and one of the side rectangles, and then I can multiply by 4.

Now, the side rectangles can be treated as the expected area if the center lies on the line KM, and then we can multiply by the side length MN. I used calculus and circular segments to compute it as (hopefully correctly):
$$ (l-2r)\left(\pi r^2 r - \int_0^\pi \frac{r^2}{2}(\theta-\sin \theta)d\theta\right) = (l-2r)\left(\pi r^3 - \frac{r^2 (\pi^2-4)}{4}\right).$$

I guess I could do something similar with the corner squares as well, which would require double integration. Is the approach correct? Is there a simpler way? Would I be counting the area on the intermediate sides such as MN multiple times?
[image: Square decomposition]

Comment: [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827640/how-to-calculate-the-probability-that-the-distance-between-two-points-is-less-th)

Comment: The approach certainly seems correct! This seems like the approach that's most conceptually simple; maybe there's some sneaky approach that's computationally simpler....